# Having issue in filter function for dates

Tags: r

I Have a date dataframe df

```
df 
Date                              Cat 
21-09-2017  22:05:00               A
22-09-2017  22:05:00               B
23-09-2017  22:05:00               C
24-09-2017  22:05:00               D
24-09-2017  22:05:00               E
```

here I am using below code to extract only Sep 24 data and Cat E, but its not working4

```
plot_data11 <- df %>% filter(Cat == "E" & Date == "24-09-2017  22:05:00")
```

I am getting error. What wrong I am doing here

Comment: Your column Date is probably as date time and not a character string. Please provide the error message and the structure of your data using `dput`.

Comment: Error in the sense, when I execute the code and ````View(plot_data11)```` the data is not there. I mean empty data.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the Date column of your dataframe to string before looking for a match with the date, looking for matching rows with `grepl`. Your example would become:

```
plot_data11 <- df %>% filter(grepl("24-09-2017",as.character(Date)) & Cat == "E")
```